# Ordenação de Lista por Campo String

Tags: c#, linq, design-pattern, classificação, enums

Eu tenho uma Lista com atributos, dos quais tenho o campo de avaliações, contendo: Excelente, Bom, Regular, Ruim, e Péssimo. As informações para este campo eu obtenho do consumo de uma API REST usando JSON.

**Exemplo:**

```
IEnumerable<minhaEntidade> minhaLista = _respositorio.ConsumirAPI();

foreach (var item in minhaLista)
{
    Retorno.Add(new minhaNovaEntidade()
    {
            Nome = item.NomeCompleto,
            Endereco = item.EnderecoCompleto,
            Avaliacao = item.AvaliacaoDesempenho
    });
}
```

**Se eu fizer:**

```
return Retorno.OrderBy(x => x.Avaliacao);
```

Eu terei a lista ordenada pelas avaliações de desempenho em ordem alfabética.

Porém, eu preciso ordenar a lista obedecendo o critério de precedência: Excelente, Bom, Regular, Ruim, e Péssimo.

Ou seja, todos os Nomes e Endereços que primeiro tenham sido avaliados como Excelente, depois Bom, depois, Regular, depois Ruim, depois Péssimo. Nesta respectiva ordem.

Já tentei criar um **[Type-Safe Enum Pattern](https://blog.falafel.com/introducing-type-safe-enum-pattern/)** para comparar a lista obtida com meu *Type-Safe Enumerator*, exemplo:

```
return Retorno.OrderBy(x => MeuEnumerador().CompareTo(x.Avaliacao));
```

ou...

```
return Retorno.Sort((x,y) => x.Avaliacao.CompareTo(MeuEnumerador().ToString()))
```

Mas não funcionou e/ou dá erro.

**Perguntas:**

Alguém já precisou fazer algo semelhante a este meu problema usando C#?

Ou ainda, tem alguma sugestão de implementação para o que estou procurando?

Lembrando que as informações não vem de banco de dados (o que seria fácil de resolver), mas de uma API JSON, e o campo é justamente uma string.

Comment: Qual o tipo de `Avaliacao`?

Comment: @LINQ o campo Avaliacao é do tipo string. E quando consumo a API, vem Excelente, ou Bom, ou Regular, ou Ruim, ou Péssimo.

Comment: `IEnumerable<minhaEntidade> minhaLista` nessa variavel já tem a lista de valores, é dai que você precisa ordernar?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Exatamente é esta lista que preciso ordenar pelo campo Avaliacao, que é do tipo string, mas não em ordem alfabética. Primeiro ordenar todos os casos que foram avaliados por Excelente, depois Bom e assim por diante.

Comment: Entendi Alexandre Dórea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `enum` para as classificações e ordene por ele:

```
public enum Avaliacoes
{
    Excelente = 0,
    Bom = 1,
    Regular = 2,
    Ruim = 3,
    Pessimo = 4
}
```

Fiz um código de exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lista Original:");

        List<Entidade> entidades = new List<Entidade>();
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =1, Nome = "Teste 1", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Ruim });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =2, Nome = "Teste 2", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Pessimo });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =3, Nome = "Teste 3", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Regular });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =4, Nome = "Teste 4", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Bom });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =5, Nome = "Teste 5", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Ruim });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =6, Nome = "Teste 6", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Regular });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =7, Nome = "Teste 7", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Ruim });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =8, Nome = "Teste 8", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Bom });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =9, Nome = "Teste 9", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Ruim });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =10, Nome = "Teste 10", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Ruim });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =11, Nome = "Teste 11", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Bom });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =12, Nome = "Teste 12", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Excelente });
        entidades.Add(new Entidade(){ Id =13, Nome = "Teste 13", Avaliacao = Avaliacoes.Excelente });


        entidades.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Nome + " / " + x.Avaliacao));

        entidades =  entidades.OrderBy(x => x.Avaliacao).ToList();


        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Lista Ordenada:");

        entidades.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Nome + " / " + x.Avaliacao));


    }


    public class Entidade
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string Nome {get;set;}
        public Avaliacoes Avaliacao {get;set;}

    }

    public enum Avaliacoes
    {
        Excelente = 0,
        Bom = 1,
        Regular = 2,
        Ruim = 3,
        Pessimo = 4
    }
}
```

> Resultado:

```
Lista Original:
Teste 1 / Ruim
Teste 2 / Pessimo
Teste 3 / Regular
Teste 4 / Bom
Teste 5 / Ruim
Teste 6 / Regular
Teste 7 / Ruim
Teste 8 / Bom
Teste 9 / Ruim
Teste 10 / Ruim
Teste 11 / Bom
Teste 12 / Excelente
Teste 13 / Excelente
----------------------------------------------
Lista Ordenada:
Teste 12 / Excelente
Teste 13 / Excelente
Teste 4 / Bom
Teste 8 / Bom
Teste 11 / Bom
Teste 3 / Regular
Teste 6 / Regular
Teste 1 / Ruim
Teste 5 / Ruim
Teste 7 / Ruim
Teste 9 / Ruim
Teste 10 / Ruim
Teste 2 / Pessimo
```

Coloquei no [**DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BD9QF2)

ps. Você vai precisar converter a String que vem no json pro enum, então: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104/4713574

Comment: vou testar converter para o Enum. Não havia pensado nisso. Assim que eu tiver o resultado avalio aqui.

Comment: não tenho certeza, mas é possível que no parse do json, ele já seja convertido pra enum automaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão para resolver o problema. Crie um campo/atributo de peso na sua `minhaNovaEntidade` . Ao adicionar o novo item a lista de retorno coloque o valor do peso. Após incluir todos os itens classificados, reordene a lista com base no peso. Exemplo:

```
foreach (var item in minhaLista)
{
   xxx = new minhaNovaEntidade()
   {
        Nome = item.NomeCompleto,
        Endereco = item.EnderecoCompleto,
        Avaliacao = item.AvaliacaoDesempenho
   };

switch (item.AvaliacaoDesempenho)
        {
            case "Excelente":
                xxx.peso = 1;
                break;

            case "Bom";
                xxx.peso = 2;
                break;

            default:
                xxx.peso = 99;
                break;
        }

Retorno.Add(xxx);

}

return Retorno.OrderBy(x => x.peso);
```

Comment: Criei um campo como sugeriu. Mas, não precisei usar o Switch. Aproveitei o conceito que eu já tinha implementado de Type-Safe Enum Pattern e retornava o valor por este enum customizado. Como fecho e dou pontos de validados ao que sugeriu?

Comment: Clique na marca ao lado da resposta Se tiver dúvida consulte https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers